# Batch - Open folder with unknown name

Tags: file, batch-file

So I want to access this specific path

```
c:\users\admin\social\profile\KoJumperz\pictures
```

but my friends name isn't `KoJumperz` so his path is not the same. His path would be

```
C:\users\admin\social\profile\JhonSmith\pictures
```

Is  there a way to create a code that will open the first folder in my profile folder?

Comment: You can use: c:\users\admin\social\profile\%username%\pictures - Look at the SET command from Windows.

Comment: Yes but %username% is the machine's username i need to open a folder with his Social name witch is difffernet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start enumerating the folders and break the loop after the first iteration:

   ```
   for /d %%d in (C:\users\admin\social\profile\*) do (set profile=%%d & goto break)
   :break
   echo Using %profile%\pictures
   ```

   To get the 2nd folder skip 1 entry of dir listing:

   ```
   for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%d in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\users\admin\social\profile\*"') do (
       set profile=%%d
       goto break
   )
   :break
   ```

   Use `skip=2` to get the 3rd and so on.
2. Or find an environment variable that may be set on the user's PC, for example `%socialusername%` (the exact variable name can be seen by running `set` in command prompt console):

   ```
   echo Using C:\users\admin\social\profile\%socialusername%\pictures
   ```

Comment: Thanks Im sure this is what I was looking for. Im still a noob in coding so if you can can you please explain your 1st code. I think think thats the best way for me to learn!

Comment: What exactly needs explaining? The best method to learn is to start with a basic tutorial actually, there should be plenty on the net.

Comment: i scanned the come myself understand most of it. could you explain just [code]echo Using [/code]and can i replace it to acutally   open the folder and not just change directory of my cmd?

Comment: `echo Some text` outputs `Some text` to console. Use `cd some_folder` to change the current directory.

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!! I FINALY MANAGED TO DO IT! The code works just as i wanted it to. Thank you very much!

Comment: if with "open Folder" you mean "open this Folder with Explorer": `explorer "c:\my path\subfolder\this folder" `

Comment: @wOxxOm also do you know how do open the 2nd or 3rd folder?