# Cmd for opening folders with unknown name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, subdirectory

I am writing a batch script that works as follows:

1. Goto certain location (for example C:/Temp/1)
2. Open the first 5 sub-directories of 1 (for example if 1 contains directories called 10,20,30, open 10. Then open 10 and if 10 also contains 10,20,30 open 10 as well, and goes on till --> 1/10/10/10/10/10)
3. List item copy all of the contents of the current folder(10) back to C:/Temp
4. Go back to C:/Temp and delete the first folder's files (1)

Now, i encounter a problem that i don't know how to open the directories
inside 1, since i don't know their names.
I am sure there is a way of opening the first folder, since i saw
a close example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147714/batch-open-folder-with-unknown-name)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you have any code you tried already to post? Also, isn't the example you gave exactly what you are looking for? Or am I missing something...

Comment: One more thing: do you want do copy only the files under the last "10" sub-directory? If not, check the `dir /b /s /a:-d` command. It will list recursively everything that it not a directory, then you can do a `for` for it and copy everything. More at `dir /?`.